# Trails forming on the front of the object

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a planet simulation thingy (kinda like universe sanbox 2 but way worse) for my college project and I can't get the trails (orbits) of the planets at the correct position.
[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viIk6.jpg)

planets is just the dictionary containing list of planet surface and rectangles

```
def revolve(n): 
    x,y,theta,inc,color = planet_data[n] 
    planet_obj = planets[f'planet{n}']              #planet_surf,planet_rect
    # the math:
        # (h-10) and (k-10) are the cenre of the circle (let it be origin), -10 for the deviation caused by the size of the image
        # x and y decide the radius
        # value at x-axis is determined by cos and value at y-axis is determined by sin 
        # theta -= <rate> determines the speed of the revoltion (minus sign because planets revolve anticlockwise)
        # theta starts from 0 i.e. at:
            #  0  : cos is max and sin is 0
            # -90 : cos is 0 and sin is min
            # -180: cos is min and sin is 0
            # -270: cos is 0 and sin is max
            # after -360 : repeat
    planet_obj[1].x = x*math.cos(theta)+(h)
    planet_obj[1].y = y*math.sin(theta)+(k)
    theta -= inc
    
    planet_data[n][2] = theta    #change the value of theta in planet_data dictinary (otherwise the planet will just stay in one position)
    trail(n,planet_obj,color)

    screen.blit(planet_obj[0],planet_obj[1])

trail_d = {}
def trail(n,planet_obj,color):
    try:
        trail_d[n].append((planet_obj[1].x,planet_obj[1].y))
    except:
        trail_d[n] = []

    try:
        pygame.draw.aalines(screen,color,False,trail_d[n])
    except: 
        None

    if len(trail_d[n]) > planet_data[n][0]:
        trail_d[n].pop(0)
```

for the full code:
https://github.com/nyxan/universe-sandbox

I've tried changing the h,k,x,y and it just made it worse
I don't know what else should I do. I want it to be just behind the planets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building your trail based on the top left position of the planet Rect. In your `trail()` function, if you change:

```
planet_pos = (planet_obj[1].x,planet_obj[1].y)
```

to

```
planet_pos = planet_obj[1].center
```

The trail will behave the way you want:
[image: Trails]

Note: this is based off the [github sandbox.py](https://github.com/nyxan/universe-sandbox/blob/main/sandbox.py), which is slightly different to the question. For the question function, the change would be:

```
trail_d[n].append(planet_obj[1].center)
```

Comment: ah I see. thanks. I already submitted it though :D